# Javascript regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a combo box and input box. If I enter any letter in input box then all the words or sentence that match with that letter should display in the combo box assuming that a list of words or sentence contain in the list.

```
ex1:)  input box: a
       combo box : America 
                   Australia
                   joy is in Austria
```

For this example I want JavaScript regex patterns. Anybody give me suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you're asking for, but I think you don't want regex, you just want jQuery:

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        $j(document).ready(init);

        function init()
        {
            $j('#MyEditBox').change( filterCombo ).keyup( filterCombo );
        }

        function filterCombo()
        {
            var InputText = $j(this).val();
            $j('#MyCombo option:not(:contains('+ InputText +'))').hide();
            $j('#MyCombo option:contains('+ InputText +')').show();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="MyEditBox" />
    <select multiple id="MyCombo">
        <option>America
        <option>Australia
        <option>Something else
        <option>Joy is in Austria
        <option>Wibble
    </select>
</html>
```

**Update:** This one will only match whole words:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();


        $j(document).ready(init);


        function init()
        {
            $j('#MyEditBox').change( filterCombo ).keyup( filterCombo );
        }


        function filterCombo()
        {
            var InputText = $j(this).val();

            if (InputText.length > 0)
            {
                $j('#MyCombo option')
                    .hide()
                    .filter(function() { return hasWholeWord( $j(this).val() , InputText ) })
                    .show()
                    ;
            }
            else
            {
                $j('#MyCombo option').show();
            }
        }


        function hasWholeWord( Text , Word )
        {
            return (new RegExp('\\b'+Word+'\\b','i').test( Text ));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="MyEditBox" value="" />
    <select multiple id="MyCombo">
        <option>America
        <option>Australia
        <option>Something else
        <option>Joy is in Austria
        <option>Wibble
    </select>
</html>
```

Comment: why was this given an negative vote?

It seems like a valid solution to me

Comment: filterCombo() where we have declare.i mean inside the ready function or outside

Comment: Well, as per the "something along the lines of", it was intended as a general example, not a precise copy-paste example. But anyhow, I've added a ready/init function in.

Comment: Actually, here we go - a full HTML example. :)

Comment: it is working for me ,but i have some condition here. when i enter 'E' in the input box i am getting America, Somethig else, Wibble. but actually it should not show any result.search should be for entire word like joy not jo . Any idea please

Comment: Ok, I've updated it now to only show results when a whole word matches. Of course, this now uses the word-boundary regex. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have the word put into a word boundary as you type.  Just replace the [word here] part below with your typing from the textbox.

The expression would be:

```
\b[word here]\b
```

Also, here's a good [regex tester](http://regexpal.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a little on where you want to match from. In your example the letter 'a' matches both at the start and the end of "America", is that a sufficient match?

Depending on how you want to filter your data you could use [jLinq (*Disclaimer: My project :)* )](http://www.hugoware.net/tryonline)

Depending on where you want to match from you may want to use the '\b' option to try and limit where an acceptable match comes from...

**\ba** - Match 'a' from the start

**a\b** - match 'a' from the end

Additionally, if you're interested in the value of the match, you could use something like the following...

**(?<1>\ba\w+)** - This is a little harder to read, but this matches anything that starts with an 'a', but also returns the entire word as a group within the match.

Comment: sorry please tell me , (?<1>\ba\w+) where i have to add this ?

Comment: something along the lines of ... str.match(/(?<1>\ba\w+)/gi) when looping through to determine which values you want to keep. If that doesn't make sense let me know and I'll post more in the answer

Comment: Yep, this works better than my answer. Also, I believe it would only match to a lowercase a and not an uppercase A, so you may want to use like .ToUpper(), or whatever it is in Javascript, and then match to (?<1>\bA\w+).

Comment: Well sorta, I left the case matching up to the actual .match() function with the /gi flag (global and ignore case)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple substring match, you don't need regex, just a plain `myString.indexOf(inputString)` should suffice. For case-insensitive you can do `myString.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputString.toUpperCase())`.